# Mount.nfs is using a serial port

Tags: mount, nfs, serial-port

I export a folder to remote hosts by configuring the /etc/export file this way in the **NFS server**:

```
/remoteFolder 172.22.0.0/255.255.0.0(ro,no_root_squash,sync,insecure)
```

and start the NFS daemon with this command:

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.nfsd start
```

In the NFS client, I am issuing this command to mount the remote folder locally:

```
mount -t nfs -o ro,bg,soft,intr,timeo=5,retrans=5,actimeo=10,retry=5 nfsServerIp:/remoteFolder localFolder
```

I have noticed that, in the NFS client, the mount.nfs command is using a serial port (e.g. ttyS3) by filtering the lsof output. **Is this OK?**

Furthermore, that serial port shares IRQ with another three serial ports. In  the same one the mount.nfs command is using, I am trying to communicate to an external device and this communication is curiously failing sometimes. I have configured /etc/serial.conf with this parameters:

```
/dev/ttyS0 uart 16550A port 0x3F8 irq 4
/dev/ttyS1 uart 16550A port 0x2F8 irq 3
/dev/ttyS2 uart 16550A port 0x3E8 irq 11 
/dev/ttyS3 uart 16550A port 0x2E8 irq 11
```

Is it possible to solve this problem? Can I force mount.nfs to use another serial port?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show evidence why you think mount.nfs is using a serial port. I find it very unlikely.

Comment: Several entries for mount.nfs appear when I type lsof | grep ttyS. I'll post them ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with another serial port (i.e. /dev/ttyS2). So I assume this effect is due to **hardware error**.

If I connect the cable to the original serial port the communication with the external device is KO again :S